# Now I have a Shape in word,Can I turn it into a image and save it?

Tags: c#, ms-word, com

I'm trying to use `ConvertToInlineShape()`.

But it is not successful,because it is a GroupShapes, its type is msoGroup.

How do I turn it into image and save as?

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape s in WordDoc.Shapes)
{
    if (s.Type.ToString() == "msoGroup")
    {
        //First try:
        s.ConvertToInlineShape();

        //Second try
        s.Select();
        WordApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.CopyAsPicture();
        Image image = Clipboard.GetImage();
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image);
        bitmap.Save("d:\\test" + i + ".jpg");
        //image in null
    }
 }
```

Comment: this shape in not inlineshapes

Comment: Try  WordApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Clipboard.GetImage());

Comment: Clipboard data is null

Comment: Is the Clipboard data not null when you called it the other way? if both are null that could be the problem accessing the clipboard. Try adding [STAThread] decorator above your main method and see if that helps.

Comment: InlineShpaes It's work,but shape It doesn't work

Comment: To my knowledge there is no way to do what you want. You could tried to ungroup your `msoGroup` convert each shape to an inline shape copy each as a picture and save it. Finally group your `msogroup` again? Another approach could be to create your group in Microsoft PowerPoint and save it as Picture to use it where ever you want. There you can use the same shapes and have the possibility to group as well.